# JSON.Net Deserialize psuedo-JSON Stream

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a stream producing the following json-like data:

```
{
  "type": "TypeA",
  "time": "2018-04-18T19:54:06.653874823Z",
  "status": "Pending"
}
{
  "type": "TypeB",
  "time": "2018-04-18T19:55:06.653874823Z",
  "status": "Pending"
}
{
  ...
```

and I'd like to use JSON.Net to bind this to my class

```
public class MyData
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

If the data being streamed were properly formatted json, i.e.,

```
[
  {
    "type": "TypeA",
    "time": "2018-04-18T19:54:06.653874823Z",
    "status": "Pending"
  },
  {
    "type": "TypeB",
    "time": "2018-04-18T19:55:06.653874823Z",
    "status": "Pending"
  },
  {
    ...
]
```

I could achieve this simply with

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

using (var sr = new StreamReader(myStream)
using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
   {
       var myDatas= serializer.Deserialize<List<MyData>>(reader);
   }
```

Is there any way to configure JSON.Net to use the json-like data shown above? Or, will I have to transform the data before I get JSON.Net to do the conversion?

Comment: You'll have to transform the data first. You can't expect the JSON deserializer to interpret something that isn't JSON.

Comment: @DanWilson - Think the `SupportMultipleContent` feature will do what I'm trying to achieve. See answer below.

Comment: Well I'll be...ya learn somethin new every day. You young bucks and yer JSON streams...